# cakePHP : populating 2 fields with the same foreign key and write to database

Tags: mysql, sql, cakephp, foreign-keys

I have a players table and a videos table. In the videos table I have 2 fields (PlayerA and PlayerB) and the values have to come from the players table. But when I have 2 foreign keys in the table videos with the name player_id it says that I have a duplicate.

Now I can only store 1 player Name to the database.

Players table:

```
1   player_id   int(11)
2   player_firstname    varchar(45)
3   player_surname  varchar(45)
4   player_birthDate    date
5   player_turnedPro    year(4)
6   player_nickname varchar(45)
7   player_nationality  varchar(45)
8   player_highestBreak varchar(45)
9   player_highestRanking   int(11)
10  player_centuryBreaks    int(11)
11  player_careerWinnings   varchar(55)
12  player_worldChampion    varchar(45)
13  player_image    varchar(255)
14  player_category varchar(45)
```

Videos table:

```
1   video_id    int(11)
2   video_title varchar(45)
3   video_date  timestamp
4   video_scoreA    tinyint(4)
5   video_scoreB    tinyint(4)
6   video_url   varchar(255)
7   tournament_id   int(11)
8   timeline_id int(11)
9   player_id   int(11) => PLAYER A
10  player_id   int(11) => PLAYER B => here it says that I have a duplicate
```

Is there a possibility to store values from a players table, that are populated in 2 fields, in a Videos table?

**Update**

videos table:

```
1   video_id    int(11)
2   video_title varchar(45)
3   video_date  timestamp
4   video_scoreA    tinyint(4)
5   video_scoreB    tinyint(4)
6   video_url   varchar(255)
7   tournament_id   int(11)
8   timeline_id int(11)
```

players_videos table:

```
1   videos_players_id   int(11)     
2   video_id    int(11)     
3   player_id   int(11)
```

Video Model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
       'Player' =>
           array(
               'className' => 'Player',
               'joinTable' => 'players_videos',
               'foreignKey' => 'video_id',
               'associationForeignKey' => 'player_id',
               'unique' => true,
           )
   );
```

Player Model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
   'Video' =>
       array(
           'className' => 'Video',
           'joinTable' => 'players_videos',
           'foreignKey' => 'player_id',
           'associationForeignKey' => 'video_id',
           'unique' => true,
       )
    );
```

VideosController in the add action :

```
$players = $this->Video->Player->find('list', array('fields'=>'player_firstname', 'player_surname'));

$this->set(compact('tournaments', 'timelines', 'players'));
```

add.ctp View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('Player.Player');
```

index.ctp View:

```
<?php foreach($players as $player): ?>
   <?php //echo h($player['player_id']); ?>
   <p><?php echo $this->Html->link($player['player_id'], array('controller' => 'players', 'action' => 'view', $player['player_id'])); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: it is possible (I mean is possible to add both columns with different names and have cake recognizing them as foreign keys), but you have to consider if it is good logic you are implementing. is there *always* going to be only two players? I see you are repeating video_player and video_score, what if you add video_rematch, video_handshake, video_player_crying_because_he_lost (or whatever), are you going to add two columns for each new attribute you want to store?

Comment: There will always be only 2 players. But if I want to store the 2 names in the database, I need 2 fields right? I updated my question.

Comment: But if sometime your project scales and you want to store two names, two scores, times, surnames, two sons_names, then maybe an association of the type Players - Player-Video-asoc (with the name, score, times and whatnot) - Videos may be more comfortable. I'm not judging your database, I'm just saying it may be easier in the future with another type of association if the thing scales. If you want to keep that db structure, check this QA that popped up after yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891498/cakephp-model-relation-having-2-foreign-key-on-the-same-table/24891692#24891692.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not recommend this approach. The HABTM association is a better alternative for this case. You can check the documentation here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm

But... what you asked for:

In your Video model:

```
public $hasMany = array(
    'Player A' => array(
        'className' => 'Player',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_a_id'
    ),
    'Player B' => array(
        'className' => 'Player',
        'foreignKey' => 'player_b_id'
    )
)
```

In your Player model:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Video' => array(
        'className' => 'Video',
        'foreignKey' => 'video_id'
    )
);
```

Rename your columns to player_a_id and player_b_id.

Comment: Maybe it's just a typo, but given the foreign key structure that should be a `hasOne` association, not `hasMany`, as multiple Player A/B doesn't make much sense. And the `belongsTo` on the other hand should actually be a `hasMany`, as a player can have multiple relations to a video, not just a single one.

Comment: I checked HABTM and implemented it in my project and it works. Still searching to display the player_firstname and player_surname instead of the player_id's in the index.ctp. I updated my question with the code I have been using for HABTM

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have two fields/columns with the same name in one table. You must give them different names. (If you wanted one in particular, how would you ask for it?) Eg call them player_a and player_b.

A foreign key column/field does not have to have the same name as the column/field it references. In SQL you would write

```
create table Videos
(....
player_a int(11),
player_b int(11),
FOREIGN KEY player_a REFERENCES Players (player_id),
FOREIGN KEY player_b REFERENCES Players (player_id),
...)
```