# CakePHP model relation having 2 foreign key on the same table

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I have this database design

```
Applicant Table
id | country_id | country_now_id

Country Table
id | name
```

The country_id is an FK to the Country Table, and the country_now_id is also an FK of Country Table. My question is how would I write this one in Model relation?

I have this code:

```
class Applicant extends AppModel { 
  public $belongsTo = array(
                      'Country'=>array(
                          'className'=>'Country',
                          'foreignKey'=>'country_id'
                        ),

                      );
                      .....
```

I don't know how to add the country_now_id and put it in that relation. I'm not even sure if using `$belongsTo` is the right way. I am still new in the CakePHP Framework. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Thank You! :)

Comment: Any specific reason why you would you want to put this into a single association (which btw. isn't possible)? What would you expect that to do?

Comment: That's just how they design the database, too bad I know..By the way, I managed to solve that one already. Thanks by the way :)

Comment: Well, it's not necessarily a bad design, I just wanted to make sure that I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve :)

Comment: @ndm Right. Well the country_now_id means where the applicant is current working, while the country_id is like where the applicant was born. :)

Answer (score 4):

Update: I managed to solve this one by doing this

```
  public $belongsTo = array(
                        'Job'=>array(
                          'className'=>'Job',
                          'foreignKey'=>'psm_id',
                        ),
                      'Country'=>array(
                          'className'=>'Country',
                          'foreignKey'=>'country_id'
                        ),
                        'NowCountry'=>array(
                          'className'=>'Country',
                          'foreignKey'=>'now_country'
                        ),
                      );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
class Applicant extends AppModel { 
    public $belongsTo = array(
                  'Country'=>array(
                      'className'=>'Country',
                      'foreignKey'=>'country_id'
                    ),
                  'CountryNow' => array(
                      'className' => ' Country',
                      'foreignKey' => 'country_now_id'
                  )

                  );
                  .....
```

That way, if you do

```
$this->Applicant->find('all', array('contain'=>array('Country', 'CountryNow')
```

for example, you'll get something like

```
Applicant1
  Country
  CountryNow
Applicant2
  Country
  CountryNow
```

You are using `belongsTo` the right way... for now. But we can't actually know for sure unless you explain to us why are you using this type of relation. For example, if you want one Applicant to have two countries, then ok, you're good. But is there a chance that an applicant will have more than two countries? If that could happen, then the structure of your models will become a pain. If you can, maybe rethink the logic, if not, let's hope there's always two countries always.